# How to hide elements in NativeScript Angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to make custom behavior swipe (RadList).

When we swipe to right, i want to hide id="right-stack",
when to left, id="left-stack".

But, directive *ngIf is not working, app is crashing.

```
<RadListView
    [items]="_dataItems"
    swipeActions="true"
    (itemSwipeProgressStarted)="onSwipeCellStarted($event)"
    (itemSwipeProgressChanged)="onSwipeCellSwiping($event)">
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
        <StackLayout class="listItemStackLayout">
            <Label class="nameLabel" text="text"></Label>
            <Label class="nameLabel" [text]="item.name"></Label>
            <Label class="descriptionLabel" [text]="item.role"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
    <GridLayout *ngIf="isVisible" *tkListItemSwipeTemplate columns="*, auto, auto" id="left-stack" class="LeftlistItemSwipeGridLayout">
        <StackLayout class="archiveViewStackLayout" col="0">
            <Label text="ARCHIVE" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout *ngIf="!isVisible" *tkListItemSwipeTemplate columns="*, auto, auto" id="right-stack" class="listItemSwipeGridLayout">
        <StackLayout class="deleteViewStackLayout" col="1">
            <Label text="DELETE" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</RadListView>
```

In component

```
public isVisible: boolean = true;
```

Comment: ngIf actually removes the element and re-creates it when needed again. Try setting `visibility` to `collapse` - https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#visibility

Comment: You are messing the core functionalities of RadListView (swipe templates) with the top abstraction (Angular structural directives) - that is not recommended and I doubt it would work not matter if using `*ngIf` or `visibility`. If the core RadListView is not supporting a dynamic change of swipe templates - then you won't be able to "work it out" by using Angular